# How can I remove all the numbers in a list except for 1 number (Python)?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want my code to remove every single number in a list except for a specific  number, which is `3`. Instead it removes certain numbers but majority of them still remain in the list.

```
myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
i = 0
for i in myList:
    print(i)
    if i != 3:
        myList.remove(i)
    else:
        continue
    i += 1
    print(myList)
```

Comment: why you are counting i ? you wanna have both indexes and values of your list ?

Comment: You are changing the list as you iterate, skipping values. Is it okay to create a new list? Then its `myList = [v for v in myList if v == 3]`.

Comment: I think you are mixing i up with an index. In Python, when you iterate through a for loop, you are iterating over each element. Therefore, there's no reason to increment it, and you don't need to initialize it prior to the loop.

Comment: The reason this does not work is because in Python, you can't modify a list you are iterating over.  That's why @tdelaney reassigned the value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Also: [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/7851470)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few issues. First, you're trying to modify the list in place, as you're trying to process it. You can fix that by changing:

```
for i in myList:
```

to:

```
for i in myList[:]:
```

That will allow your code to give the desired result. It makes a "copy" of the list over which to iterate, so you can modify the original list without messing up your iteration loop.

The other thing to note is that you assign a value to *i* in the `for` loop, but then you manually change it after your `if-else` block. That change gets discarded when you go back to the top of the loop.

Also, you're `else: continue` prevents incrementing *i*, but it doesn't matter, because that incremented value was just getting tossed anyway.

So... commenting out some of the unnecessary stuff gives:

```
myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
# i = 0
for i in myList[:]:
    print(i)
    if i != 3:
        myList.remove(i)
    # else:
        # continue
    # i += 1
    print(myList)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems. First, the `for` loop iterates the list values, not its index. You can use `enumerate` to get both the index and the value. Second, if you delete values in a list, its remaining elements are shifted down by 1 but since the iterator also increments by 1, you miss a value. A trick is to iterate the list in reverse so that any deleted values have already been iterated.

```
>>> myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> mlen = len(myList)
>>> for i, v in enumerate(reversed(myList), 1):
...     if v != 3:
...         del myList[mlen-i]
... 
>>> 
>>> myList
```

But this operation is slow. If you don't need to modify the original list, use a list comprehension

```
>>> myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> myList = [v for v in myList if v==3]
>>> myList
[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are removing elements from the list you are iterating over. So your loop won't iterate over the entire list.